# Ruby (RoR) XML to hash and then show in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have some xml on server (http://server.com/my.xml). Here is the example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE current PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<current>
  <song>Bruce - Inside The Machine</song>
  <song>02 Duel of the Fates 1</song>
</current>
```

On Rails application I do:

```
response = open("http://server.com/my.xml").read
@sngs = Hash.from_xml(response)
```

Now, in Views, I want to put each "song" value in "p" tag for example, but *not* one by one. I have to put, for example exact first or second.

How can it can be done?

(Many, many thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash.from_xml will create a Hash of the form:

```
{"current" => {"song" => ["Bruce - Inside The Machine", "02 Duel Of the Fates 1"]}}
```

I'm not entirely sure what you want to display, but you can access individual songs using:

```
@sngs["current"]["song"][0]
```

If you wanted to display all the songs inside p tags, for instance, you could do:

```
<%- @sngs["current"]["song"].each do |song| %>
  <p><%= song %></p>
<%- end %>
```

Comment: Thank you! This exact what i need! Thank you Greg!