# Losing xml data when parsing date and time in Savon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, soap, savon

I'm using Savon in my RoR app.

This is my call to the service:

```
client = Savon::Client.new(MY_SOAP_CLIENT)

response = client.request :wsdl, :get_history do
    soap.body = "<startDate>2011-09-23</startDate><endDate>2011-09-24</endDate><userId>3</userId>"
end
```

And I'm getting the next response in XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">
<resMessage xmlns=\"http://xxx-xxx.xxx.edu/xxx/\">
    <result>date=2011-09-23?amount=13.00?time=08:50:38?user=a00123?type=transfer</result>
    <result>date=2011-09-23?amount=3.00?time=08:51:27?user=a00123456?type=transfer</result>
    <result>date=2011-09-23?amount=20.00?time=09:49:00?user=a00123456?type=transfer</result>
</resMessage></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

But, the main problem is when I call `response.to_hash` I only get the Date objects part:

> => [Fri, 23 Sep 2011, Fri, 23 Sep 2011, Fri, 23 Sep 2011]

This is great for the date, but the other part of the results are missing: amount, time, user and type. Also if I call `response.body` I keep getting the same results:

> => {:res_message=>{:result=>[Fri, 23 Sep 2011, Fri, 23 Sep 2011, Fri,
>   23 Sep 2011, Fri, 23 Sep 2011, Fri, 23 Sep 2011],
>   :@xmlns=>"http://xxx-xxx.xxx.edu/xxx/"},
>   :"@xmlns:soapenv"=>"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"}

I didn't find the solution for this here nor Savon Issues

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
h = Hash.from_xml(response.to_xml)
```

and that would give you a correct hash.

[Ruby (RoR) XML to hash and then show in views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684195/ruby-ror-xml-to-hash-and-then-show-in-views)

Comment: Thanks Syred! That was really helpful!
I hope the Savon folks could take a look at this issue.